# adding a simple system call to linux kernel

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, system-calls, kill-process

I've just added a system call to the linux kernel. It simply takes a `char*` argument name and prints Hello name.

This is system call code:

`asmlinkage long sys_hello(char* name) { printk("Hello %s \n", name); return 0; }`

and this is the code which should run the system call for testing:

```
int main() 
{
    long int amma  = syscall(318,"Winston");
    printf("Returned %lu \n" ,amma);  
    return 0; 
}
```

but when I run this, I get a killed output.
Any ideas about fixing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is executed in kernel context whilst the buffer with data comes from the userspace. If you need to process some string from the userspace, copy it to the kernel memory using [strncpy_from_user()](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/asm-generic/uaccess.h#L175) function. If you don't follow the scheme and simply try to access the data directly, this will lead to a memory access violation.

A better solution (based on your code) would look somewhat like this:

```
asmlinkage long sys_hello(char* name) {
    long  nb_symbols;
    char *name_internal;
    long  i;

    /*
     * Estimate the buffer length sufficient
     * to accommodate the string
     */
    for (i = 1; ; ++i) {
        nb_symbols = strnlen_user(name, i);
        if (nb_symbols <= 0)
            return -EFAULT;

        if (nb_symbols < i)
            break;
    }

    /* Allocate the storage */
    name_internal = kmalloc(nb_symbols + 1, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (name_internal == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM;

    if (strncpy_from_user(name_internal, name, nb_symbols + 1) !=
        nb_symbols) {
        kfree(name_internal);
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    printk("The 'name' is '%s'\n", name_internal);
    kfree(name_internal);

    return 0;
}
```

However, please note that such a loop (as one in my example) might not be an acceptable solution for buffer length estimation. Ideally, you could drop it and use a static `char` array of fixed length to use `strncpy_from_user()` with.

Comment: this can't be an infinite loop since the range of user memory is finite. however, lack of explicit upper bound is quite problematic. instead of hand-rolling this machinery you should strndup_user instead. regardless, given the gravity of the mistake OP is doing something fundamentally wrong and that's the problem which needs addressing. Giving them something to effectively copy-paste is imho the wrong thing to do. So far it seems OP just copy pastes off of a bad tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the classic examples how to NOT write kernel code - it tries to directly access the userspace buffer which is an extreme no-no.

If you got a crash, that's probably SMAP in action. Hard to say for sure since you did not provide the log.

So the real question is: where did you take the above from? are you doing a university course which has the above in its material?

Comment: Yes, this is a university assignment, but the code is mine, they haven't provided any information about how to write such a function. Besides my classmates have used this code and worked fine for them. How is that possible if this approach is wrong?

Comment: cmon dawg. most of adding a syscall of the sort is just boiler plate, are you claiming you came up with everything yourself? I also already gave you a keyword as to why it may break and noted where the result is stored (the kernel, accessible with 'dmesg'). See https://lwn.net/Articles/517475/ . Either way, your approach to programming is wrong - what you should do is check what existing syscalls do to access said memory and you will find the most definitely NOT just read/write. I can only hope your TA is aware that code of this sort is wrong and will point it out.

Comment: I didn't come up with the whole thing! Based on this link https://tssurya.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-3-16-0/ we wrote this function. Anyway, Thanks for your help.